# 9 bottles of beer on the wall, 9 bottles of beer, if one of those bottles should happen to fall

Tags: calculation-puzzle

```
100 / 5 = 14 
30 + 30 = 60
50 * 2 = 120
100 - 5 = ?
```

What is the answer, that should be in place of the question mark?

Comment: I think it's 64.
Pressed for time, no time to give informative answer, so it;s a comment.

Comment: I am unsure if i should say if it was correct or incorrect in the comments. Could you also elaborate a bit more later on on how you go there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is

> 73

The trick is

> All numbers are given in Octal

Some deductions I made:

> 30+30 works, so the math is probably right in a different base,
> 50*2=120 got me to Octal, which confirmed my suspicion based on the question title.

Incidentally, 100/5=14

> Works in Integer Division, in regular mathematical division, it results in a remainder.

Comment: ha, ninja'ed because I was taking the extra time to explain that the division on the first line had to be taken as truncating :-).

Comment: Oh, good point, I'm kinda used to Computer-style division, I'll comment that in

Comment: This is indeed right